# Regular expression for not allowing alphabets at the start of string

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to develop a regular expression which does not allow the string to start with a number. For example, see the following test cases

```
445test=>false
test555=>true
test_test45=>true
```

i.e. a string that starts with a number is not allow.string may contain any special characters.

Comment: Your question title and body conflict. Don't start with number? `^\D`. Don't start with alphabetical? `/^[^a-z]/i`

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
[^0-9]

That is same as \D

Refer to [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) for more information